# Windows 10: How to disable this notification?

Tags: windows, windows-10, notifications, notification-area, notify-osd

This insanely annoying notifications keeps up showing up daily:

[image: notification]

How could I please disable it? I remember doing something with `regedit` about this, but it didn't work apparently.

There is no such option to disable it on the menus.

I don't want the computer to ever reboot by itself or remind me of the active hours, I will reboot it manually or just let it apply the update when I turn it off.

Windows 10 version: Enterprise LTSC 1809

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you the computer will restart OUTSIDE of active hours, not inside active hours (when you have defined when you will be using the computer).

The update has been installed and you cannot stop  this message.

Be certain Active Hours have been properly set and work for you.

You can pause the restart for several days (I am not certain how many) but you cannot install anything else in the meantime because of the pending restart.

Best approach is the set Active Hours and then let restarts happen outside of your active hours.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has decided users cannot delay restarts past a certain time.
In the advanced options, you can 'schedule' it for up to seven days out, but then this notification will come back, and *will* reboot next night.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Edit Group Policy"

- Go to: Computer configuration and click Administrative templates.
- Go to: Windows components > Windows Defender Security Center > Notifications
- Open the Hide non-critical notifications setting and set it to Enabled. Click OK.

source material [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-security-center/wdsc-hide-notifications#:%7E:text=Windows%20Security%20%3E%20Notifications.-,For%20Windows%2010%20version%201803%20and%20below%20the%20path%20would,Click%20OK.)